# How to double import a module for test purposes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing

Currently I have a module that when It is `import`ed a `for` loop is executed:

`numbers.py`

```py
DICT_NUMBER = {
    'one': One,
    'two': Two,
    'three': Three,
    'four': Four,
    'five': Five,
}

for num in DICT_NUMBER.values():
    if not issubclass(num, Number):
        raise Exception(f'{num} is not extending Number')
```

The problem is that I don't know how to test it, I've tried to do the following code:

```py
from numbers.py import DICT_NUMBER # the for is executed without raise Exception

DICT_NUMBER['A'] = A # 'A' don't extends Number

with self.assertRaises(Exception):
   from numbers.py import DICT_NUMBER
```

This does not work because `DICT_NUMBER` turns into a unresolved reference.

There is any way to do it?

Comment: it's probably better to use a type checker to enforce this rather than a test -- `DICT_NUMBER: dict[str, type[Number]] = { ... }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot double import a module, only reload it as specified here: [how to reload a python module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437589/how-do-i-unload-reload-a-python-module). In your case module file is not changing so reload will not help. Try to move the `for` part into a function with a `dict` parameter and then test it with different inputs.

Comment: I made this solution even before seeing your comment, so I will mark it as an accepted answer.